# UITableView value not rendering until screen is re-rendered

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with a detail label on the right.  This label is populated by a entity that I populate from a JSON call in my connectionDidFinishLoading function.  The problem is that the cellFromRowAtIndexPath function fires before the connectionDidFinishLoading function so I don't see the values in my table view until I pull down on the screen which redraws the page.  I have tried refreshing the table view at the end of both of these functions but that doesn't see to work.  Can someone give me a clue as to why this is happening and how I can fix it please.

[image: What the initial load looks like]

[image: What the refreshed view looks like after I pull down on the screen]

Comment: Try `setNeedsLayout` or `setNeedsDisplay` on the tableview. And make sure the tableView outlet is connected.

Answer (score 1):

you have to reload your table data at the end of your connectionDidFinishLoading.
two ways:

The first:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

The second:

```
NSArray* rows = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion before I posted here...that didn't work for me.

Comment: I tried your second suggestion and that didn't give me any different results than before...can you recommend something else please?  I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `reloadData` in the main thread? `connectionDidFinishLoading` sounds like it's running in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

After populating, call `reloadData` on the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. All UI updates and manipulations must be performed from the main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```